# Ran Pycharm debug which ended with exit code -1

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Just a quick question but I ran Pycharm debug on a lengthy series of test scripts and the end result was:

```
"Process finished with exit code -1"
```

I was just wondering what this means given that exit code 0 is a pass and exit code 1 is a fail. (is it super awesome code to end in -1?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be seeing that exit code because of a [bug in PyCharm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10155).

Comment: 2017, still getting this.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a bespoke issue, but for some reason my `Associate this virtual environment with the current project` had become unchecked, and re-checking it fixed this bug for me.